# Who is Brezhnev's aide on this 1978 photo?

Tags: soviet-union, photograph

Here is [Brezhnev](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonid_Brezhnev) awarding the [Order of the Red Banner of Labor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_the_Red_Banner_of_Labour) to chess player [Karpov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatoly_Karpov) on 27 Dec 1978.
Who is the man smiling in the background?

[image]

Comment: What is the source of the photo? What research have you already done?

Comment: I searched for images of Brezhnev & Karpov, and found one that implies that the  third man is  [Victor Korchnoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Korchnoi). Although I'm not good at facial recognition, [chess.com](https://www.chess.com/news/view/viktor-korchnoi-1931-2016-1214) image of Korchnoi seems similar.

Comment: I am not sure Korchnoi would have been [welcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viktor_Korchnoi#Defection) at a Soviet awards presentation  in 1978.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It’s [Michail Georgadze](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B7%D0%B5,_%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BB_%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87), secretary of the Supreme Soviet, who is mostly known just for signing all the state award orders during the late Brezhnev's period.

Here is an annotated copy of your image from  a Russian state photography archive: https://photo.rgakfd.ru/photo/129046 (mirror: https://photo.rgakfd.ru.office.kaisa.ru/photo/129046)